# d3 How to properly update svg circle radius in a zoomed map?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm working on a map of italian cities classed by dimension (more people -> bigger radius)
here a preview (inspect it for the full code) http://www.danielepennati.com/prove/mapping/ita_popolazione.html 
when you zoom in the map I scale the radius and it works fine

```
s = d3.event.scale; //s is defined in the main function  
g.selectAll('circle')
  .attr("r", function(d) { return raggioCittà(rateByIdCF[d.id][anno]) / s; })
```

If you use the select on the left of the map to change the year and update the circle radius with the new data... if the map is not zoomed everything goes right
if the map is zoomed I try to set the scaled radius (if I log of the radius the value is correct), but in the the "r" value of the circle elements it is the not scaled one and the circle are, obviously, too big.
this is the code that update the circle on year selection:

```
g.selectAll(".punto_comun")
        .data(topojson.feature(base, base.objects.com2011_g).features)
        .attr('fill', function(d) { 
          if(rateByIdCF[d.id]){
            if(raggioCittà(rateByIdCF[d.id][anno]) < 4){ return '#0042b0'}
          }
          return '#ff0000';
        })
        .attr("r", function(d) { 
          if(rateByIdCF[d.id]){
            //check if map is scaled, if yes scale the radius down
            if(s){ return raggioCittà(rateByIdCF[d.id][anno] / s);  }
            //if not use the standard radius
            return raggioCittà(rateByIdCF[d.id][anno]); 
          }
        })
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work right... maybe I'm missing something about the zoom behavior.
I'll really appreciate any advice.
thanks
daniele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following code structure:

```
var s;

function move(s, t) {
  s = ...;
}
```

The `s` variables there refer to different things. The top level `s` is shadowed by the `s` in the declaration of the function `move`. That is, `s` inside `move` refers to the first argument, not the global `s`. Any changes to it affect only that argument (and therefore have only local scope) and not the `s` you want to change.

To fix, simply use different variable names.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I removed the s and t parameter (they were there for error...) but nothing changed. I add some log so you can see I can pass the s value correctly and the r calculated by "raggioCittà(rateByIdCF[d.id][anno] / s)" shud be right. make a try: zoom in and change year and just check the console log. Thanks again Lars!!!

Comment: You have a typo in your update function -- `raggioCittà(rateByIdCF[d.id][anno] / s)` should be `raggioCittà(rateByIdCF[d.id][anno]) / s`.

Comment: No way... Thank you so much Lars! I haven't seen this typo for all the day!!! Now everything work fine. thanks again

Comment: just to share... I have updated the map changing the use of crossfilter to address the multiplication of .dimension() and the breaking of the script after few selection. thanks again for the help